# Error executing jar file with maven dependencies. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/opengis/feature/type/Name

Tags: java, maven, geotools

I'm exporting my java app into a single JAR file but when I try to execute it I always get the same error.

*java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/opengis/feature/type/Name*

Apparently there is something wrong including the *opengis* dependencies.

I am using the *shade* plugin and the `mvn package` command to generate the JAR file.

Here I include my `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
  <artifactId>DataEngine</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>DataEngine</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <geotools.version>23-SNAPSHOT</geotools.version>  
    <start-class>exe.Main</start-class>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
       <artifactId>gt-epsg-hsql</artifactId>
       <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
           <artifactId>gt-geotiff</artifactId>
           <version>${geotools.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
           <artifactId>gt-image</artifactId>
           <version>${geotools.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
           <artifactId>gt-wms</artifactId>
           <version>${geotools.version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-graphx_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-service</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opengis</groupId>
        <artifactId>geoapi</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

 <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net repository</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>osgeo</id>
            <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
            <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>boundless</id>
          <name>Boundless Maven Repository</name>
          <url>http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spark graphx</id>
            <name>spark graphx</name>
            <url>https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-graphx</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spark hive</id>
            <name>spark hive</name>
            <url>https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-hive</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spark sql</id>
            <name>spark sql</name>
            <url>https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql</url>
        </repository>
         <repository>
            <id>jdbc hive</id>
            <name>jdbc hive</name>
            <url>https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-jdbc</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>hive service</id>
            <name>hive service</name>
            <url>https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-service</url>
        </repository>
         <repository>
            <id>mysql driver</id>
            <name>mysql driver</name>
            <url>https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>commons-loggin</id>
            <name>commons-loggin</name>
            <url>https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>opengis</id>
            <name>opengis</name>
            <url>https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.opengis/geoapi</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.6</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>

 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>exe.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>      

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <artifactSet>
                        <includes>
                            <include>junit:junit</include>
                            <include>org.geotools:gt-shapefile</include>
                            <include>org.geotools:gt-swing</include>
                            <include>org.geotools:gt-epsg-hsql</include>
                            <include>org.geotools:gt-geotiff</include>
                            <include>org.geotools:gt-image</include>
                            <include>org.geotools:gt-wms</include>
                            <include>org.apache.spark:spark-graphx_2.12</include>
                            <include>org.apache.spark:spark-hive_2.12</include>
                            <include>org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.12</include>
                            <include>org.apache.hive:hive-jdbc</include>
                            <include>org.apache.hive:hive-service</include>
                            <include>mysql:mysql-connector-java</include>
                            <include>commons-logging:commons-logging</include>
                            <include>org.opengis:geoapi</include>
                        </includes>
                    </artifactSet>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>exe.Main</mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Here the full error trace which I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/opengis/feature/type/Name
    at exe.Main.initialize(Main.java:119)
    at exe.Main.main(Main.java:86)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.opengis.feature.type.Name
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more
```

I would really appreciate any help/suggestion. I've been stack at this point for quite a long time but still not getting any solution.

Comment: Which IDE are you using? If it is intellij check whether all the dependencies downloaded or not.

Comment: I'm using eclipse. They should be correctly downloaded.

Comment: You specified the version as ${geotools.version}. Where it will get the value for that? Or try specifying exact version.

Comment: I've change it by 22-RC version (found it on the maven web site) but still getting the same error :(

Comment: You should use the latest stable version 22.0 (https://geotoolsnews.blogspot.com/2019/09/geotools-22-released.html) rather than a release candidate.

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid the maven assembly plugin as it will cause you [issues](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175669/add-raster-layer-or-a-wms-using-geotools-problem-to-run-the-jar-file-from-cmd) in the future. [GeoTools](https://geotools.org) modules often define one or more files in its META-INF/services directory with the same names as files defined in other modules. The assembly plugin just copies files with the same name over the top of each other rather than merging their contents.

The good news is that the [Maven shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html) can be used instead and it will correctly merge the META-INF/services files from each of the GeoTools modules used by your application.

See the [FAQ for more details](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/build/faq.html#how-do-i-create-an-executable-jar-for-my-geotools-app).

And finally, please use a stable release unless you are explicitly testing the release candidate for us (22-RC for example, became useless on the release of 22.0).

Answer (score 1):

I've added this assembly plugin:

```
<plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>exe.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id> 
            <phase>package</phase> 
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

But is still not working

**SOLVED: **
I just had to add `<sourceDirectory>src/com/foobar</sourceDirectory>` to `<build>` and execute the `mvn clean compile assembly:single` command.

Comment: It strange. How many org.opengis.feature.type.Name class in your project? Did you try to run with mvn package or mvn clean package?

Comment: I use it quite a lot. Now I've tried both commands but not working at all.

Comment: I mean how many org.opengis.feature.type.Name class that exists in your whole project. I think it could be that you have more than one org.opengis.feature.type.Name class in your project and ClassLoader get confused.

Comment: If you are using eclipse you can do quick search for absolute name by press ctrl+shift+T then paste org.opengis.feature.type.Name in the prompt box.

Answer (score 0):

There is another plugin if you want to build your entire app to a single jar: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

Maven assembly also support various type of packaging. You can consider using this if you cannot find a way to fix your current problem.